# Finding and studying Poincaré map

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I know what the definition of a Poincaré map is but I am struggling a little bit with the exercises and with computing it. I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given the system (in polar coordinates):

$$ \dot{r} = r + \alpha r^3 $$
$$ \dot{\theta} = \nu       $$

with $\alpha < 0$. Find the solutions of the system and write the corresponding Poincaré map for a section $\theta =$ constant. Study the dynamics of the Poincaré map (one-dimensional map). Any help with how to proceed is welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: The first equation is Bernoulli, you can give an explicit solution formula. The second equation tells you for what time interval.